# Jekyll ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, webrick

I'm getting the following error in my console logs when running the `bundle exec jekyll` command.

```
[2020-01-29 15:34:01] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:16 
        /Users/aeum3893/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
        /Users/aeum3893/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
        /Users/aeum3893/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-01-29 15:34:01] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:17 
        /Users/aeum3893/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
        /Users/aeum3893/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
        /Users/aeum3893/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
```

After that, I can go to my localhost:4000 which is the one where I'm working on this proyect, but I'm getting a weird behavior in my styles. The images that have the `hover` effect does not work, or other kind of weirdness in the navbar, and so on.

This is a webpage that is using SiteLeaf as a CMS and being deployed with AWS.

I highly appreciate your help... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Running `bundle exec jekyll s` removes these messages but I'm also interested in knowing why it comes to be if just running the `jekyll s` command.

These messages are persistent when the site rebuild itself after reload.

Comment: I found that my problem with my styles was because I was using the ```--incremental``` flag in my build command, however, I still this webrick errors when reloading the application. I haven't found a solution yet, but doesn't seem to be affecting the app so far

Comment: Started seeing those weird errors when running the jekyll server locally as well, doesnt seem to impact the app though.

Comment: I haven't noticed an impact either, it's just extra junk in my terminal that pushed down any actual errors I have. not ideal, but I can take a deep breath and accept the imperfections lol.

Comment: Seeing these error messages with `bundle exec jekyll s` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to serve images dragged from mac Photos Version 5.0 (161.0.120).

If the image had been edited, then the file created after dragging still looks like a jpeg but it's really a HEIF:

```
❯ file *
IMG_4943-drag.jpeg:   ISO Media, HEIF Image HEVC Main or Main Still Picture Profile
```

An image that has NOT been edited drags from Photos OK, the resulting file IS a jpeg.

Also, using Photos' Export function on an edited image works as expected.

```
IMG_4943-export.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try previewing the site at localhost: 4000 rather than 127.0.0.1:4000. That did the trick for me. I think it's a CSS relative paths thing.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to happen after upgrading Jekyll versions, with a `.jekyll-cache` and/or `_site` directory from a previous build.

The fix is easy, just delete both of those directories and restart Jekyll.

Comment: I followed the steps above and was unable to produce the solution. I'm still getting the errors.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me either. Running Jekyll 4.2.2.